# Unit testing for exceptions that were catched

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mockito, powermock

```
public void methodToBeTested() {
    try {
       //Some logic that throws an exception
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      //Logic dealing with an exception
    }
}
```

Well, with ExpectedException we can check if the method under test has thrown any exception, but how to check it the exception has occurred when method in not throwing, but catching it?

Comment: if you call a service inside the catch block, you can test whether or not that servicecall occured

Comment: or by rethrowing the exception from catch

Comment: @pvpkiran that's changing the actual application. I doubt that's what they want

Comment: Your code has `//Logic dealing with an exception`. Verify that this logic was executed.

Comment: @khelwood Actually the catching code doesn't have ant logic apart from logging..

Comment: @Stultuske You're correct re-throwing that exception would change application flow..and as it's not thrown I'm striving to deal with such scenario..

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for understanding the problem..! Please let me know when you find the solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

(If you cannot verify the logic dealing with the exception, for example it's some log) In your test:

1. mock the "Some logic that throws an exception" to throw some exception
2. call the `methodToBeTested`
3. test is OK if no exception is thrown during the call (and if there's one the test will fail automatically if using junit)
4. *verify* the mocked "logic" [optional]

Comment: That's wud be workaround, I want to check if that exception was occurred..:(